# Flask-SQLAlchemy MySQL Connector: 1045 (28000): Access Denied, but seems capable of accessing database

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

EDIT: After some help in the comments and some extra troubleshooting, I walked back my package upgrades one at a time and identified that this breaks in one or both of these upgrades:

- Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1 -> 3.0.2 (Could be 3.0.0 or 3.0.1. There's [another issue](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/1122) preventing me from getting more granular.)
- SQLAlchemy 1.4.48 -> 2.x

Note that I was able to successfully run `flask db upgrade` without error after re-upgrading Flask, Flask-Migrate, and mysql-connector-python to the higher versions noted below, so long as I had Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1 and SQLAlchemy 1.4.48 installed. So this error does appear to stem from one of those packages.

I've edited the rest of the question below to focus it, given this new info.

/EDIT

---

I have a confusing error that doesn't seem to be answered in the other questions about this particular error. I have a Flask server using Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to a MySQL database. I recently updated some of my packages:

- Flask: 2.0.2 -> 2.3.2
- Flask-SQLAlchemy: 2.4.3 -> 3.0.3
- Flask-Migrate: 2.5.3 -> 4.0.4
- mysql-connector-python: 8.0.26 -> 8.0.33

among a number of others. The update went fine. Today I went to deploy a new feature that required a database migration. I ran `flask db upgrade` and got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
   (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1045 (28000):
   Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost'
   (using password: YES)
```

I also get this when I try other `flask db ...` commands.

I've done a ton of troubleshooting and am confident that the user is fine and SQLAlchemy is using that correct user in the correct database. I added a list of what I did to come to this conclusion below.

- I manually entered the mysql terminal with `mysql -u my_user -p` and my new password, and it worked just fine. I could enter commands and view things in the database.
- I double-checked my new password in the config file. It's still the correct format: `"mysql+mysqlconnector://my_user:my_password@localhost/my_db"`
- I saw answers saying that special characters can be trouble so I tried URL-encoding the special characters and even made a new password without any special characters. I flushed privileges after each change. Same error.
- I verified that I have no other MySQL instances running on my machine.
- I checked that the port in the MySQL instance that I can log into is standard (3306). I also tried adding the port to my db uri in the config (i.e. `"...@localhost:3306/my_db"`). Same error.
- I checked my MySQL version (8.0.33, the latest, and matches the connector) and tried restarting it.
- I checked that the user does indeed have the correct permissions, and was actually able to create a table manually from within the MySQL CLI tool.
- I tried creating a new user with full permissions. Same error.

Comment: Maybe start a `flask shell` and once in it print `app.config` to see what database URL is being used? Clearly it must not be the correct one, for some reason.

Comment: Just tried: `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]` is the same as in my config file. `db.engine.url` is the same as well and `db.engine.url.password` shows the valid password that I've been using to log into MySQL on the command line.
(P.S.: I really appreciate all the resources/tools you've published over the years!)

Comment: I'm not really sure then. I would look at logs on the MySQL side to see if there is any clues there, I guess. But I've never had this type of problem, so I'm not really sure if the MySQL logs will be of help.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Ok, thanks for the ideas. I checked out the logs and saw that my user is able to do SELECT / UPDATE / INSERT statements, but is denied during the CREATE TABLE statement during `flask db upgrade`. Weirdly, they do have permission to create tables and can even create one from within the MySQL CLI tool. So it seems maybe this issue lives somewhere in the `mysql-connector-python` package...

Comment: Hm. I just created a table with this user using a connection via `mysql.connector` like shown in the `mysql-connector-python` [Getting Started guide](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python#getting-started). Such a head-scratcher...